# Get primary user of device through SCCM query in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm, wql

We're scanning the active directory to find all computer objects. Then for each machine we're trying to find the user that used that machine the most, i.e. the primary user.

To find this data we found 2 working queries towards SCCM:

```
$Query = "
SELECT
    SMS_R_User.FullUserName, SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName, SMS_R_System.Name
FROM
    SMS_R_System
INNER JOIN
    SMS_G_System_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE
    ON
    SMS_G_System_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
INNER JOIN
    SMS_R_User
    ON
    SMS_G_System_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE.TopConsoleUser = SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName
"
```

```
$Query = "
    SELECT
        SMS_R_System.name, SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName
    FROM
        SMS_R_System
    INNER JOIN
        SMS_UserMachineRelationship
        ON
        SMS_UserMachineRelationship.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
    JOIN
        SMS_R_User
        ON
        SMS_UserMachineRelationship.UniqueUserName = SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName
      WHERE
       SMS_UserMachineRelationship.Types = 1
    "
```

We execute these with:

```
    $WmiParams = @{
        Namespace    = "root\SMS\site_EU1"
        ComputerName = $SCCMServer
        Query        = $Query
    }

    $Result = Get-WmiObject @WmiParams
```

We're not much of SCCM experts but both queries give different results and duplicate computer objects `$Result.SMS_R_System.Name | Group-Object | where Count -ge 2`.

What is the correct query to have one machine name connected to one primary user with `SamAccountName` and `FullUserName`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SMS_UserMachineRelationship` should contain Primary device for users. It's possible that 1 device can be Primary device of many users, and also 1 user can have more than 1 Primary device. It depends on the criteria configured in `Client Settings` to identify Primary device. By default if some users logs into a device for `48 hours` in a month then it's considered as Primary device of that user. This criteria can be changed. You may read more about `User Device Affinity` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/link-users-and-devices-with-user-device-affinity

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use the PowerShell module "dbatools"...

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "myserver.contoso.local" -Database "CM_P01" -Query "select UniqueUserName,MachineResource Name from v_UserMachineRelationship"
```